# Failed "Provisioning Your iOS Device for Generic Development"

Tags: iphone, xcode, organizer

I have been developing on an iPhone 3GS for sometime now, and recently got ahold of an iPhone 4 to do some testing. With the iPhone 4 connected, I pressed the button in Xcode Organizer ["Use for development"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-devices_organizer/articles/provision_device_for_development-generic.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010392-CH1) but I didn't have an Internet connection and the "Use for development" step failed. Now, the "Use for development" button does not appear with this phone connected, and even if I remove the phone from the Organizer, when I reconnect the phone, I still don't get the "Use for development" button again. Anyone know the physical path on Mac OS X where the settings for an iPhone relevant to development are contained? (I.e., so I can properly reset these settings).

Thanks!

Comment: "Use for development" should still work even if you do not have a connection to the Internet. Do you see the Identifier?

Comment: what version of iOS is your iPhone 4 running? which version of Xcode are you working with?  I suspect you're running an older OS on your phone while your Xcode is looking for iOS 6 or newer.

Comment: I missed an important part to my question. Ooops. I can't run apps on the phone yet, from Xcode. I'm using Xcode 4.5.2 and the iPhone 4 is running iOS6.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have the certificates installed on the iPhone. (Its somewhere in settings app on the iPhone)

If you do and they are valid you should be all set.

Did you add iPhones UDID to your ios developer account?

Comment: Using Organizer, I have installed 3 Profiles on the iPhone. I am able to get a single app (using adhoc deployment) to run, but I want to generically use this hardware for testing.

Comment: These 3 profiles show up in the settings app on the phone. Yes, I added the iPhone's UDID to my ios developer account.

Comment: Do you mean you are *not* able to get apps running using ad hoc distribution?

Comment: I am able to get apps to run using ad hoc distribution, but am unable to get generic apps (i.e., without going through the apple provisioning portal) on the phone.